# Chromedriver not recognizing Options

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run chromedriver on PyCharm for MacOS:

```
options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
```

But the code keeps throwing an error:

```
File "/filepath/file.py", line 28, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=optionss)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

How to resolve this? I downloaded the 81.0.4044.69 version from ChromeDriver [website](https://chromedriver.chromium.org) and placed it in the file path.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"path of chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)

Comment: Thanks Dipak, it gets the job done. But, the code isn't working in headless mode now. Chrome keeps opening and closing for every value it needs to scrape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample example to launch chrome in headless mode.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"path of chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=options)
driver.get('your url')
```

**Another solution** :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1400,800")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"path ofchromedriver.exe",options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: Thanks Dipak, I changed to code to include the commands shared above, but it still keeps opening the Chrome window.

Comment: I have verified above code and its working absolutely fine without any issue.

Comment: Edited the post to include the complete code, Dipak.

Thank you!

Comment: The issue isn't resolved, Dipak. You asked me to post the code and I did.

It still doesn't trigger a headless mode.

Comment: I have added another solution, I have verified it its working in heeadless mode for me. Can you please try to create separate .py script to just test above code whethher its workin g iin headless mode so that you will get to know atleast whether its working in headleess mode and then you can make amendment in your code to resove issue

Answer (score 0):

P.s. The actual error is because of a typo

```
options=optionss -> options=options
```

Make sure every thing is installed properly

```
pip install selenium
```

Then try using this code as an example to make sure headless mode is activated, by taking a screenshot.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# Set Chrome options for running in headless mode
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

# Path to the chromedriver executable
chromedriver_path = "path/to/chromedriver"

# Initialize Chrome WebDriver with the specified options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver_path, options=chrome_options)

# Open a website
driver.get("https://example.com")

# Get info from the page
title = driver.title
print("Page Title:", title)

# Take a screenshot
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
print("Screenshot saved as screenshot.png")

# Close the WebDriver
driver.quit()
```